# select from menu after right click watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver, I am able to right click on an element using this code snippet:

```
s = @browser.span :text => 'Inbox'

s.right_click
```

After this I am doing this to select an item from the new menu that pops up:

```
@@browser.send_keys :down
@@browser.send_keys :enter
```

But that does not work.

Am I missing anything here? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

First try changing @@browser to @browser.

Comment: in my code @browser is @@ browser, its a static member variable, there was a typo in @ browser.span.

Comment: That's all I have, sorry. I've never had good luck with right click menus. Maybe take a look at autoit.

Comment: thanks, I was able to solve this, after right clicking, I used the ID of the element to locate the element and then clicked it, that worked :)

Comment: Can you post how did you get the ID or help by posting an answer about your accomplishment ?