# Watir-webdriver for Safari Cannot Right Click or Double Click

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

On Mac 10.9, my watir-webdriver scripts work with Chrome and Firefox, but with Safari I cannot right click or double click. Trying to double click or right click gives me this error:

> button available? true
>   /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/bridge.rb:73:in `raw_execute': Unknown command: mouseMoveTo (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in`execute'
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:399:in `mouseMoveTo'
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:52:in`move_to'
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:62:in `move_if_needed'
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:26:in`context_click'
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:344:in `block in perform'
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:343:in`each'
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.40.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb:343:in `perform'
>       from /Users/engineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.8/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:165:in`right_click'
>       from tester.rb:10:in `'

Here is my code. On the last line, if I changed the right click method to left click, it will click on the "I'm feeling lucky" button. Does anyone know what why this error is happening? I've just started using Watir. I followed the steps to get watir-webdriver working on Safari from here: www.watirwebdriver.com/safari/

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :safari
b.goto "http://google.ca"

puts "button available? #{b.button(:id => 'gbqfba').exists?}"
b.button(id:'gbqfbb').span(text:"I'm Feeling Lucky").wait_until_present
b.button(id:'gbqfbb').span(text:"I'm Feeling Lucky").right_click
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not adding a comment(dont have the rep for it yet), so dont treat this as an answer. But have you tried adding an id to the span and trying to select it by that instead of by the text? [select from menu after right click watir-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709650/select-from-menu-after-right-click-watir-webdriver) seems to have had issues with the right click as well and solved it by using id to select the element

Comment: Yes i have. Adding the span section in my code was unnecessary with the button id already there.